# IBM Worklight 6.0 Should redeploy WAR if a new environment was added?

Tags: deployment, war, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

We are working on a Proj X. In the first release Android env was supported. Regarding deployment,the WAR was deployed into a WL Server.
Later on, a new Environment is going to be added (Windows 8), so thru eclipse we add this new env and do build. 
PS.: Nothing was changed on the project server side wise, so Adapters, java libs, worklight.properties and authentication remains the same.

The new projx_windows8.wlapp is created.

Should the WAR be redeployed or just load the new wlapp thru the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to deploy the .war file, since you did not change anything in it.
Only deploy the .wlapp for the added environment.